# Trying to add code to calculate distance between two user entered points

Tags: c, distance

I've got a working program that asks users to select either to write to a file or read it. If the user selects to write, the program will ask for two points which will then be printed to the file in the format of "Point (%d,%d)". What I'd like to do is be able to calculate the distance between each point so that if the user wishes, the total distance can be displayed. To clarify, the distance would be (Point1->Point2)+(Point2->Point3)+(Point3->Point4), not Point1->Point4. I believe I will have to use some equation like this:
distance += sqrt((int)(...some short values being calculated...)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
typedef struct point
{
        short int x;
        short int y;
}point;
int main(char ** args, int argc)
{
        point append;
        char choice;

        int i = 1;
        int c;
        char dump;

        while(i != 0)
        {
                printf("Enter a to append and c to calculate p to print\n:");
                scanf("%c%c", &choice, &dump);

                switch(choice)
                {
                        case 'a':
                        {
                                FILE * output;
                                output = fopen("test.bin", "ab+");
                                printf("Enter the x:\n");
                                scanf("%hu", &append.x);
                                printf("Enter the y:\n");
                                scanf("%hu%c", &append.y, &dump);
                                fprintf(output, "Point (%hu,%hu)\n", append.x, append.y);
                                fclose(output);
                                break;
                        }
                        case 'p':
                        {
                                FILE * print;
                                print = fopen("test.bin", "rb");
                                if(print)
                                {
                                        while((c = getc(print)) != EOF)
                                        {
                                                putchar(c);
                                        }
                                }
                                fclose(print);
                                break;
                        }
                        case 'q':
                        {
                                i = 0;
                                break;
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Note: Suggest `scanf(" %c", &choice)` instead of `scanf("%c%c", &choice, &dump)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [distance formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance) to find the length of each segment. Add those segment lengths to find total distance.

The distance formula takes the square root of the sum of the squares of changes in x and y:

```
Distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
```

Where `dx` is `x2-x1` and `dy` is `y2-y1`.

Comment: I guess my real question would be then how do I implement such a thing?